# Kendo grid doesnt populate from API request

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am using Kendo UI, specifically the kendo grid and the kendo dataSource.

I'm getting data from a local API. The data is retrieving correctly (checked in postman). I save (or tried to save) the result of this get result in a kendo dataSource.

Then I pass this dataSource as a parameter when creating the grid. Unfortunately, the grid doesn't show any result...

Here is the code:

```js
<script>
        var inputLe = localStorage.getItem("storageLe");


        $(document).ready(function () {
            var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read:{
                    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/reg",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    type: "GET",
                }
            },
            schema:{
                //data: "data",
                model:{
                   // id: "id",
                    fields:{
                        id: { type: "number" },
                        Number: { type: "string" },
                        Date: { type: "date" },
                        Amout: { type: "number" },
                        Net: { type: "number" },
                        Category: { type: "string" },
                        Commen: { type: "string" },
                        Entity: { type: "string" },
                        Quart: { type: "string" },
                        Confirmed: { type: "boolean" },
                        Stat: { type: "boolean" }
                    }
                    }
            },
            //serverFiltering : true,
                   //filter : [
                       // {field: "Legal_Entity", operator: "eq", value: "3800" },
                //]
              
            });
      

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: gridDataSource,
                height: 700,
                editable: "incell",
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                toolbar: ["excel", "pdf", "search",{name:'new', text:'Create Comment', iconClass:"k-icon k-i-plus"}],
                dataBound: onDataBound,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [
                {
                    field: "Number",
                    title: "Number"
                }, {
                    field: "Date",
                    title: "Date",
                    format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                }, {
                    field: "Amout",
                    title: "Amount"
                }, {
                    field: "Net",
                    title: "Net"
                }, {
                    field: "Category",
                    title: "Category"
                }, {
                    field: "Commen",
                    title: "Comment",                     
                    width: 300
                }, {
                    field: "Entity",
                    title: "Entity"
                }, {
                    field: "Quart",
                    title: "Quarter"
                }, {
                    field: "Confirmed",
                    title: "Confirmed",
                }, {
                    field: "Stat",
                    title: "Status",
                 
                }

               
                ]
            });
            
        });
        
        window.localStorage.removeItem("storageLe");

        //edit to fetch in the comment drodown the categories
        function clinetCategoryEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input required name="Commen">')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: false,
                dataTextField: "CategoryName",
                dataValueField: "CategoryID",
                dataSource: {
                    data: categories
                }
            });
    }
        //function that set the boolean status of Stat and show matched or unmatched with colors
        function onDataBound(e){
            var grid = this;
            grid.table.find("tr").each(function(){
                var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
                var themeColor = dataItem.Stat ? 'success' : 'error';
                var text = dataItem.Stat ? 'Matched' : 'Unmatched';

                $(this).find(".badgeTemplate").kendoBadge({
                themeColor: themeColor,
                text: text,
            });
                
            });
        }
        
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.silver.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pako_deflate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/daterangepicker.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
           <h1>Some</h1> 
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="container">
        <div id="grid"></div>
     </div>
```

here is a sample json return from the API:

{
"id": 512,
"Number": "00000",
"Date": "2000-05-01T03:00:00.000Z",
"Amout": -999.99,
"Net": 0,
"Category": "00",
"Commen": "Some comment",
"Entity": "1234",
"Quart": "2",
"Confirmed": 1,
"Stat": 1
}

Thanks in advance.

Edit1: Put all the functions on the code snippet.

Edit2: print screen of the console and network tabs.

Edit3: new print screen usins json instead of jsonp (CORS error)

[image: network screen with the 200 return from the API]

[image: console print screen with no errors (only this warnings)]

[image: json instead of jsonp - CORS error]

Comment: Your grid definition specifies the use of functions 'onDataBound' and 'clinetCategoryEditor' but they are not shown in your code. If they are missing, the grid will not instantiate. Check the browser tools console for errors. If you remove those lines from the grid definition does it then work?

Comment: Hello @NigelK thanks for your comment and time trying to help me. As you see I edited the post to show the functions and removed them from the columns field of the grid, the problem keep hapening. For better understanding i sent 2 screenshots of the console and network tabs. If you see the code retrieve the api data but i think i'm missing something at the dataSource or the grid code.

Comment: Have you checked in `dataBound` that the grid actually has data (e.g. console.log...)? Have you tried `json` instead of `jsonp` as your data type? Have you isolated the problem by hardcoding the data in `DataSource`? So instead of `transport`, did you try `data: [...]`?

Comment: Hi @jpllosa thanks for your comment. 1- The grid has no data, i tried to see in the dataBound as you sugessted but no data was printed in the console log. 2 - i made an edit to show what happen if i use the json instead of jsonp (CORS error) and dont get retunr from API 3 - Yes i'm actually working with a copy paste from postman in the data:[] argument of the dataSource. This is why I have this databound  and clinetCategoryEditor functions. I use this with my hardcode data. I Even removed this functions from the grid and dataSource, no data got fetched :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a grid populated with data based on your example. As per my comment "did you try `data:[...]`", you replied there is no data. In this example, the grid shows the data. This means the problem isn't it your grid. It must be in `transport`. Is your localhost api returning an array? As your example code is unclear and not a minimum reproducible working example I hope the example below will help you pinpoint your problem. Try it in the Telerik DOJO or anywhere you like.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: [{ "id": 512, "Number": "00000", "Date": "2000-05-01T03:00:00.000Z", "Amout": -999.99, "Net": 0, "Category": "00", "Commen": "Some comment", "Entity": "1234", "Quart": "2", "Confirmed": 1, "Stat": 1 } ],
            });
            
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: gridDataSource,
                height: 700,
                editable: "incell",
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                toolbar: ["excel", "pdf", "search",{name:'new', text:'Create Comment', iconClass:"k-icon k-i-plus"}],
                //dataBound: onDataBound,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [
                {
                    field: "Number",
                    title: "Number"
                }, {
                    field: "Date",
                    title: "Date",
                    format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                }, {
                    field: "Amout",
                    title: "Amount"
                }, {
                    field: "Net",
                    title: "Net"
                }, {
                    field: "Category",
                    title: "Category"
                }, {
                    field: "Commen",
                    title: "Comment",                     
                    width: 300
                }, {
                    field: "Entity",
                    title: "Entity"
                }, {
                    field: "Quart",
                    title: "Quarter"
                }, {
                    field: "Confirmed",
                    title: "Confirmed",
                }, {
                    field: "Stat",
                    title: "Status",
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using a structure like this, and as you said, this helped me find my problem. I set up a node express API with MySQL, and here is where the problem is. Just for sure, I tested with an API from an external service, and it worked! I will fix this in my node backend. Since the postman gets results, I wasn't thinking that the problem is in there. Again many thanks for helping me see where my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The @jpllosa answer help me to find where the issue is. Just adding this answer to explain better how I fix this.

I'm using a node express backend to communicate with my MySQL database, and here I have to allow cors use (if you not familiar with cors, I recommend this link: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/)

So my main problem is I'm waiting for a "JSONP" when my data is a "JSON". With the "JSON" type i was receiving the CORS error message as you can see in my last image from the original post.

To allow cors I used the following code in my `server.js` file:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
   origin: '*'
}));
```

In the mentioned link you can see how to add specific domain to your API or use all domains with the "*" character.

Again, thanks to @jpllosa for his answer and time helping me here.